# pythontex custom commands for pyconsole

Tags: python

I'm trying to use PythonTex (v 0.14), its `pyconsole` environment, and custom commands, and having some trouble. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[article,letterpaper,times,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\pythontexcustomc{py}{a=1; b=2} 

\begin{document}

\begin{pyconsole}
print a
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

The result is an error that `a is undefined`. How can I execute custom code for pyconsole? I've tried `\pythontexcustomc{pyconsole}`, `\pythontexcustomc{py}`, and `\pythontexcustomc{console}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `\pythontexcustomc{pycon}{a=1; b=2}`. `pycon` goes with the `pyconsole` environment, while `py` goes with the `pycode` environment.  Everything console-related uses `pycon` somewhere in the name.